# Rect error in Python 3.6.2, Pygame 1.9.3

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, rect

I have recently been learning python and I just found out about sprites. They seem really useful and I have been trying to make a game where you have to eat all the red apples (healthy), and not the blue apples (mouldy). An error occurred when I tried to run it and it said:

```
   line 32, in <module>
   apples.rect.y = random.randrange(displayHeight - 20)
   AttributeError: type object 'apples' has no attribute 'rect'
```

Sorry if I have made a really nooby error but I have been looking for an answer elsewhere and I couldn't find one. Here is my entire main code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 800
displayHeight = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
gameCaption = pygame.display.set_caption("Eat The Apples")
gameClock = pygame.time.Clock()

class apples(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 10])
        self.image.fill(red)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

applesList = pygame.sprite.Group()
allSpriteList = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(50):
    apple = apples(red, 20 , 20)

    apples.rect.y = random.randrange(displayHeight - 20)
    apples.rect.x = random.randrange(displayWidth - 20)

    applesList.add(apple)
    allSpriteList.add(apple)

player = apples(green, 20, 20)

def gameLoop():

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

        pygame.display.update()
        gameClock.tick(60)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Thank you for reading and I look forward to a response!
(P.S. This code isn't completely finished if you were wondering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to change the `rect` attribute of the class here not the rect of the instance, and since the class doesn't have a rect, the `AttributeError` is raised.

```
apples.rect.y = random.randrange(displayHeight - 20)
apples.rect.x = random.randrange(displayWidth - 20)
```

Just change `apples` to `apple` (the instance) and it should work correctly.

```
apple.rect.y = random.randrange(displayHeight - 20)
apple.rect.x = random.randrange(displayWidth - 20)
```

Comment: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) recommends to use camelcase names for classes, e.g. `class MyClassName:`, lowercase is for variables and functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was also wondering how I would display these sprites. There's probably a really simple answer but bear with me I'm a beginner.

Comment: Take a look at [chapter 13 of Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13). It shows you how to use sprites and sprite groups. You just put all your sprites into a group (name it for example `all_sprites`) and then call `all_sprites.update()` and `all_sprites.draw(gameDisplay)` in the main loop to update all sprites and draw them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like skrx said.  you just have to single one out.
    for apple in apples:

should work.